# PHP Factory Class Inheritance Issue

Tags: php, factory

I have worked on my own factory class that instantiates dependencies and passes through constructs when a dependency is set/requested. If the dependency is cached ( Has already been instantiated by another class ) i pass that class instance instead of instantiating all over again ( mainly used for db connection ). The issue i am having at the moment is as follows.

** To avoid a large question & save reading time i am attempting to illustrate the issue as simply as possible, if the actual code is needed i can paste in.

```
Class View {
    // Construct Requests User Model
}

Class Controller {
    // Construct Requests User Model & Class View
    $this->user->set($newuserid);
    $this->view->display('file');
}
```

So `Controller` is instantiated, since `View` is set as a dependencies it is instantiated and passed to `Controller` via `__construct`. Everything is fine, but for things like a profile page. Where i set a new user ( illustrated above ) setting the new userid also alters the userid that is contained within the `View` User Model. I am not using static vars so i am confused as to why changed made in `controller` affect the `view` user model. This causes an issue for me because the logged in User's ID is set via entry point of site ( bootstrap ) & errors are caused when the profile page overwrites the logged in users id. I have added a `newInstance` option within my factory, to instead instantiate a new user model for the user profile. Things work fine, but i am still curious as to why i had/have this issue.

Comment: I am not sure what is the question you're trying to ask. can you post user model class and add comment where does that unintended change happen?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP5, variables that hold objects do not contain the actual object itself, but an identifier to reference the actual object.

So when you pass objects around, you actually pass a copy of the identifier to the object which of course points to the same object.

> [PHP Docs on Objects and references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php)

So when you use the same user object in both, your Controller and your View and manipulate it, the actual User Object will be changed. Since both object variables still hold the same identifier to the object, the objects state will be the same in your Controller as well as in your View.

```
<?php

class User {

    protected $name;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->setName($name);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

}

class View {

    protected $user;

    public function __construct( User $user )
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        echo $this->user->getName();
        $this->user->setName('Tony');
    }

}

class Controller {

    protected $user;
    protected $view;

    public function __construct( User $user, View $view )
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->view = $view;
    }

    public function someAction()
    {
        $this->user->setName('Thomas');
        $this->view->render();
        echo $this->user->getName();
    }

}

$user = new User('Jeffrey');
$view = new View($user);
$controller = new Controller($user, $view);

$controller->someAction(); // Output: ThomasTony
```

The cruicial thing to understand is that both, the View and the Controller are referencing the same object, thus manipulating the object in one class will result in also manipulating it in the other class (technically that's wrong because both just point to the same object).

---

Now let's use the clone keyword in the View:

```
public function __construct( User $user )
{
    $this->user = clone $user;
}
```

Now the `$user` property of the view will hold a "pointer" to a copy of the user object. Changes made on that object will not affect the initial object that was passed.

Thus the output will be: `JeffreyThomas`

**I want to lose a few words of caution:**

- Instead of cloning the object you should rather make sure to have clean way of flow of your objects. Your View should not manipulate the state of the User once it got passed.
- Using clone can lead to undesired behavior. If someone passes an object to one of your classes and expects class to alter the objects state (we're not talking about "Views" here) while it doesn't it can give them a very hard time of debugging.

Comment: I thought the var held its own instance of the object thank you for the help. I do not clone the classes i just pass them and assign the way you did in your view example. To solve this issue should i pass a new instance of the user model to the profile controller? The view doesn't alter the user model, it requests the userid to determine if user is logged in, if yes, an off canvas menu is created with logged in user information. Pages like the profile where i use the user model to determine the profile being viewed, the data is altered by the controller changing userid in the view.